# How to auto-select single search returns with select2

Tags: jquery-select2

The UI designer wants the select2 live search to complete when the 'matcher' function reduces the option set to 1 value, w/o having to press the enter key etc.

Is there a select2 setting for this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider providing the information and relevant code of what you have done to accomplish this and why is it failing. Show the others where you are stuck and what you have tried so far in order to allow others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch "results:all" event and trigger "result:select" - it will select currently highlighted item.

```
var select2 = new Select2({});

select2.on("results:all", function (params) {
    if (params.data.results.length === 1) {
        select2.trigger('results:select');
    }
});
```